# Changing the font of "Appendices" (\appendixpagename) on \appendixpage for appendix package?

Tags: fonts, appendices

If the option `page` is provided to the `appendix` package, it adds a page (the `\appendixpage`) stating

> Appendices

before the actual start of the appendices. The name "Appendices" is given by `\appendixpagename`. From the package documentation:

```
\newcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
\clear@ppage
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
\null\vfil
\markboth{}{}%
{\centering
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
}
```

It clearly uses `\normalfont` for the font of the `\appendixpagename` but I want to use `\sffamily` instead. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the `\appendixpagename` can be done on multiple ways:

Either use a `\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixname` and refer to the old definition or use `\xpretocmd`, see the different versions below:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[page]{appendix}

\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixpagename
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily\appendixpagenameorig}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\begin{appendices}
  \section{Foo Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

or with `\xpretocmd`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[page]{appendix}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily}{}{}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\begin{appendices}
  \section{Foo Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The 2nd way is shorter, but requires an extra package.

[image]

Comment: I've used your first solution. Works fine. Thanks you very much!